# Roles not working - erroneously appears as if User is not in a Role, .NET 6 (upgrading from .Net Core 3.2)

Tags: asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I am trying to migrate to .NET 6 for a web site from .NET Core 3.2. Specifically, getting the ASP.NET Identity element to work. I am preferring to use Dapper, and have implemented a `DapperStore` such that:

```
public class DapperStore : IUserStore<AspNetIdentityUser>,
        IUserPasswordStore<AspNetIdentityUser>,
        IUserEmailStore<AspNetIdentityUser>,
        IRoleStore<AspNetIdentityRole>,
        IUserRoleStore<AspNetIdentityUser>,
        IQueryableRoleStore<AspNetIdentityRole>,
        IDisposable
```

(Where `AspNetIdentityUser` and `AspNetIdentityRole` inherit from `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole`)

I am using the same database as used in the 3.2 version to preserve logins.

I have achieved this and am able to log in, with the following in my `Program`:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<AspNetIdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddUserStore<DapperStore>()
    .AddRoles<AspNetIdentityRole>()
    .AddRoleStore<DapperStore>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I also have, later:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

However, Roles do not work. I know for a fact that one user has the `Admin` role, but none of these methods return this:

In a method within the Page Model:

```
bool b = HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"); // always returns false
```

On a class within the Page Model:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
```

Also, I have placed `NotImplementedException`s in all my implementations for `IRoleStore<TRole>` and can confirm these never get called.

I have to be missing something.

Comment: Can you share more information? what authentication type are you using? jwt or cookie ? and login post processes.

Comment: Hi, I'm using ASP.NET Identity, for usual web page login process. So Cookie-based. The log in pages are usual default ASP.NET Identity pages. However, I don't think this is material because I have demonstrated (to myself) that any Roles that a user is a member of (having successfully logged in) are not being respected (either `IsInRole` doesn't work, or attributes don't work).

Comment: Did you check `HttpContext.User` claims? I think, Roles hadn't  added to cookie.

Comment: What do you know, I just tried. And now the `IUserRoleStore<AspNetIdentityUser>.GetRolesAsync` method is called. Difference is the login cookie was expired. I suspect this, combined with some cleaning up of code has made it work. Thanks for your thoughts, which led me to this path.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a policy I was able to get around this issue without too too much extra coding.  Not sure why the default settings are broken. (.NET 6)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", "Admin");
    });
});
```

and then adding it to the controller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdminRole")]
public class ProfileController : Controller
```

Can also use:

```
ClaimTypes.Role
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code a bit more you can c+p this just make sure to add it to the DI scoped.  (Note this is using the ClaimTypes.Role so we can use the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" claim type instead of the JwtClaimType.Role which is just "role")

```
    public class RolesAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RolesAuthorizationRequirement>, IAuthorizationHandler
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,  
                                                   RolesAuthorizationRequirement requirement)  
    {  
        if (context.User == null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)  
        {  
            context.Fail();  
            return Task.CompletedTask;  
        }  

        var validRole = false;  
        if (requirement.AllowedRoles == null ||  
            requirement.AllowedRoles.Any() == false)  
        {  
            validRole = true;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            var roles = requirement.AllowedRoles.Select(r => r.ToUpper());
            var userRoles = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value.ToUpper());

            validRole = roles.Intersect(userRoles).FirstOrDefault() != null;
        }

        if (validRole)  
        {  
            context.Succeed(requirement);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            context.Fail();  
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for many roles, for instance Admin or SuperAdmin, this code works for me:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, new[] { "Admin", "SuperAdmin" });
    });
});
```

You can also check something like this, in theory this should also work, but  in my case it isn't:

```
options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminOrSuperAdminRole", policy =>
{
    policy.RequireRole("Admin", "SuperAdmin");
});
```

Of course you have to use it like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdminRole")]
public class ProfileController : Controller
```